# Заполнение матрицы random положительными и отрицательными числами

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте!
Как можно сделать заполнение матрицы случайным образом, чтобы числа были и положительные, и отрицательные?
Положительными знаю, что вот так.

```
randomize;
   for i:=1 to n do
      for j:=1 to n do
         matr[i,j]:=random(10);
         write(matr[i,j]:5)
         writeln;
```

Что нужно изменить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отрицательные можно получить из положительных нехитрыми арифметическими операциями. Например, мне нужны числа от -10 до 10. Получаем случайное число от 0 до 20 и вычитаем 10. Все.